# Gradle errors while adding dependencies in build.gradle

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I've tried to included cards library in my project using the below code in my build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
dependencies {
    //Core card library
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.0.1'

    //Optional for built-in cards
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-cards:2.0.1'

    //Optional for RecyclerView
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-recyclerview:2.0.1'

    //Optional for staggered grid view support
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-extra-staggeredgrid:2.0.1'

    //Optional for drag and drop support
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-extra-dragdrop:2.0.1'

    //Optional for twowayview support (coming soon)
    //compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-extra-twoway:2.0.1'

  }
 }

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
}
```

But when compiling, android studio is throwing up errors as below.

Error:(23, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:

The project 'cardslib_1' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

I'm guessing the reason to be gradle version, which is lower in libraries I'm including.
How to know the gradle version my dependencies are using and how to adjust them to my project.
When I thought to add the libraries, maven has repositories in aar file which I don't think will let you know the gradle version.
Thanks for any help in this regards.

Comment: You're not applying the 'java' plugin (or any equivalent), so no plugin is creating the compile cofiguration. Shouldn't these dependencies be added to one of the sub-projects?

Answer (score 4):

You're adding the dependencies in the wrong place. They should be outside of the buildscript section and in the modules/applications build.gradle.

Parent build.gradle. This should be in the root directory of your project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Module build.gradle. This should be in the folder of the module you're trying to add the dependencies to.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    // Android related settings go here
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-cards:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-recyclerview:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-extra-staggeredgrid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-extra-dragdrop:2.0.1'
}
```

This assumes that the structure of your project is something like

```
Project
|___build.gradle
|___Module
    |____build.gradle
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Andre Compagno.

Comment: No problem! If this solved your issues please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: I'm new here, no sufficient reputation.