# Error:(23, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [file collection] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl...?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am importing new project into Android Studio, After importing I am getting an error in consoule:

> Error:(23, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [file
> collection] on object of type
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>
> `<a href="[openFile:E][1]:\Programs\Abclearn\build.gradle">Open File</a>`

For more details can you please check the image:

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle errors while adding dependencies in build.gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011099/gradle-errors-while-adding-dependencies-in-build-gradle)

Comment: This is not duplicate of that question for more information, you can check in image.

Comment: Am  tried that process but my problem was still alive.

Comment: Write your error logs. It's highly possible that the project you have imported were previously ran by a different version of gradle or Android SDK Platform tools.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `compile project(path: ':samplejavelib')` instead of

```
compile project(':samplejavelib')
```

it'll work. let me know